# NetInfo from @redux-offline/redux-offline Invariant Violation error in react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-community-netinfo, redux-offline

After successful build I try to run react native application on the IOS simulator but I've got an error:

```
Invariant Violation: NetInfo has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/netinfo' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo
```

But I import `NetInfo` from `@redux-offline/redux-offline` library. I suppose this library imports `NetInfo` directly from "react-native". After upgrading `@redux-offline/redux-offline` to the latest version `"^2.6.0-native.1"` the issue is still here.
Also I tried to remove `NetInfo` from the app but I still have this problem.
My version of react-native is "0.63.3".
Are there any possible variants how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.